# My insert function won't read a part of my struct

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct CourseNode
{
    int CNumber; //course number
    string CName; //course name
    string IName; // instructor name
    struct CourseNode* Next;
};

struct CourseNode* Start = NULL;
```

here is where the problem starts, if i write cout<< temp->iname; the program ends, here it won't equate to the y string.
if i try to remove Iname completely then cname starts to have this problem if i done cname works fine perfectly

```
void CourseInsert (int num, string x, string y)
{
    //declaration of temp
    struct CourseNode* Temp;
    Temp = (struct CourseNode*)malloc(sizeof(CourseNode));

    Temp->CNumber = num; //equating num to course number
    cout<<Temp->CNumber<<endl;

    Temp->CName = x; //equating x string to course name
    cout << Temp->CName<<endl;
    //HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
    Temp->IName = y; //equating y string to instructor name
    cout << Temp->IName << endl;
}
```

this is my main function

```
int main()
{
    int num = 7; //temporary input
    string x = "math";
    string y = "jake";
    CourseInsert(num, x, y); //calling function
}
```

Comment: `Temp = (struct CourseNode*)malloc(sizeof(CourseNode));` use `new` what you have written leads to Undefined Behaviour.  This is UB `Temp->CNumber = num;` as `Temp` does not point to a properly created  `CourseNode`

Comment: `malloc` is a low-level `new`, which itself is a low-level primitive. Use automatic allocation or a smart pointer. Or just write C rather than C++, if you find yourself using `malloc` a lot

Comment: The `malloc` function allocates memory *only*. It does not initialize the memory in any way, and it doesn't construct your object (call its constructor).

Comment: Another detail: You leak what you allocate ... You could rewrite that function: `void CourseInsert(int num, string x, string y) { Start = new CourseNode{num, x, y, Start}; }`

Comment: @RichardCritten I think `Temp->CNumber = num;` is the only valid line in his code. Why are you pointing it out? :'D The problem lies with the uninitialized memory where the strings live.

Comment: Because even though the mistake was lines earlier, the actual UB happens at `Temp->CNumber = num;` Such is the nature of bugs: They often cast suspicion on the innocent to distract from their evil deeds.

Comment: @AdamZahran it's the 1st dereference of `Temp` and as it does not point to a correctly constructed object this is UB in C++ (but probably valid C).  Code after that line (and code before it) it irrelevant as the 1st instance of UB makes the entire program meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :D

Your struct has `std::string`. Which is a C++ class that has a constructor.

When you use `malloc()`, you grab memory. But that memory is not guaranteed to be initialized to any meaningful values. It will be just garbage. That means that your `std::string` objects' internal state will be messed up. For example the place where it stores how big the string is could hold `-2` or a rabbit. No one knows!

In order for an `std::string` object to be properly initialized with proper values, its constructor must be called.

So you can instead use `new` which will allocate memory just like malloc, but it also calls the constructor for you.

You use it like this:

```
CourseNode* Temp = new CourseNode;
```

Which will call the default constructor of your CourseNode class, which will in turn call the constructor of the member variables `CName` and `IName` which insures that your memory is properly initialized and is ready to be used.

Also, don't forget to use `delete` when you're done using your memory :D

Comment: Or don't use dynamic allocation at all. There doesn't seem to be a need for it here, though that should rapidly change once `CourseInsert` is updated to actually insert the course.

Comment: Thankyouu soo much!! it worked!! this troubled me a lot since I have used malloc() in c++ to create all sorts of dynamic linked lists and binary trees and it has always worked quite flawlessly so this was a revelation!